# Variable not seen as string using getCurrentUrl in protractor

Tags: javascript, promise, automation, protractor

My goal is to store the current URL from one test case on a global variable and use it to access the URL from another test case

My global variable:

```
let loan_id;
```

After searching a bit on the internet I've found out that getCurrentlUrl doesn't return a string, it returns a promise, not know what that is i investigated a bit further and found out how to solve it.

```
    loan_id = browser.getCurrentUrl();
    loan_id.then(ln_id => {
        console.log(ln_id);
```

This is one of my tried fixes, but in the end i get the same error:

```
   Failed: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of ManagedPromise
```

Please explain to me why does the variable still behave as a promise after i tried to deal with it in the code above. I've tried all the posibilities which i've found on the web, including toString() but no luck...

Comment: I think your problem is before this block

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov what do you think could cause such a problem?

Comment: make sure whatever you pass to browser.get is a valid string

Answer (score 0):

```
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(ln_id=> {
        loan_id= ln_id;
    });
```

This is the correct way that worked for me